# three.js Alpha failing to blend

Tags: three.js, alpha, blending

What it should look like.

[image: What it should look like.]

What it does look like.

[image: What it does look like.]

So I have an object that has transparency enabled, the things surrounding the central object. If alpha is turned up to 1 they look just as they should. But they are meant to be alpha blended, and they are not blending with the central object.

You can see two in the top right of the "What it does look like" picture that are overlapping and causing a change to one another's color. But the ones that overlap the central object are only alpha blending with the white background color.

Very weirdly, the problem seems not to be with the *material*, because it was fine when I tried an almost-identical mesh with a clone of the material on it - that's how I got pic 1.

By the way, I'm generally loving threejs.

Comment: There isn't much information here to provide any help. Try providing a jsfiddle!

Comment: Not to worry, I have solved the problem. It is a weird one.

So there are three objects in this scene, ok? And they're all in one array. And because of some weirdness, I had initialized them out of their order in the array. Basically it was:

meshes[0] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);
meshes[2] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);
meshes[1] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);

What has fixed this is that I changed it to

meshes[0] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);
meshes[1] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);
meshes[2] = new THREE.Mesh(etc, etc);

Comment: Had the problem again! Setting alphaTest: 0.5 in the materials worked